# arm-eabi-gcc - cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

I am working in windows under cygwin application. I am trying to build the ndk android and a sip library. I receive the error arm-eabi-gcc command not found. How to solve it? Thx

Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Right click on my computer -

```
goto properties -> environment variable -> system variables -> path -> ;<cygwin path>
```

And then try again.